# How do I take off a suit in NBA 2K14 my career?

Tags: nba2k14

I just bought a suit in NBA 2K14. When I tried to put this suit on, I noticed that the game was placing it directly on top of the suit that was currently being worn, making me look ridiculous during post-game interviews.

Is there any way to stop this from occurring?

Comment: ...wait... whoever designed the "put clothes on top of clothes" thing should be lined up next to the "Technical fouls should be a thing in video games" guy, and those people should be slapped simultaneously.